# should we handle all things via plugins and components in october cms?

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms

I am new to october cms. i learned somethings about themes and pages and ... .

i use rainlab blog plugin.

i want to show author section in post page.
now i am using this function in php section to display user post, title, publish date and ... .

```
//pages/post.php
<?php
     function onEnd(){
        $this['post'] = $this->post; //for access to {{ post.variables }} in template
     }
?>
```

and i display post details: `{{ post.title }}`, `{{ post.user.first_name}}`.

1. should i make a plugin or top way is true?
2. when should we make plugin?
3. is there a **faster and true way** instead of plugins?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the blog plugins components default markup with your own and add your author information there.

To do that you should learn about overriding plugin components markup here

https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components#customizing-default-markup

I also think you would benefit by watching this video to help you understand how to use and set up Rainlab's blog plugin.

https://vimeo.com/97088926

Lastly, I dont think you need to use the onEnd() php function. The author/user information is available to you in {{ post }} and can accessed as you mentioned using...

```
{{ post.user.first_name }}
```